# How do I allow a user to send me a email in crafter 3.0?

Tags: groovy, crafter-cms

I am new with crafter 3.0 and right now I am creating a blueprint, one of the sections in my template is the well known "Contact" page where the user writes a message and send it to the site's administrator, I have made all the models,templates and the page is working, but I do not know how to implement the 'send message' feature, is there any control to do that or should I need to create the respective controller?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this helper class (scripts/classes/commons/service)
https://gist.github.com/cortiz/234bcdca1d7f24b3c3fce0c3703f1b45#file-emailservice-groovy
and then use 
https://gist.github.com/cortiz/234bcdca1d7f24b3c3fce0c3703f1b45#file-contact-us-groovy in the controller of the page

Since its a new class you might need to rebuild the context using this:
http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/projects/engine/api/site/context/rebuild.html